# selectizeInput: most choices don't load

Tags: r, shiny

I have a strange problem illustrated in the code below.  I create a data frame with label and value columns and update selectizeInput with it on the server side.  The server works in that a number (say, dozens) of entries are searchable, but the majority of my 9000 entries cannot be retrieved by search.  If I try to set server=F, then instead of values the labels themselves show up as the result of search.  server=F behavior is completely broken, while server=T is acting as if only a small fraction of items are cached and the rest are ignored.  Any thoughts?

P.S. The data frame was constructed with stringsAsFactors=F

P.P.S. The problem seems to be that my labels share identical prefixes - only 9 unique prefixes for 9000 labels when only the first 5 characters are used for searching.  However, I do not see how to tell selectize to use more than 5 characters (which seems to be the # used based on which strings are and are not found).

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(stringi)
library(shinydashboard)
library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)

MyMap = read.csv('MyMap.csv', row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(MyMap) = c('label', 'value')

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(

    # Application title
    dashboardHeader(title="Example Search App"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    dashboardSidebar(
      disable=TRUE
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            column(12,
                selectizeInput(
                    inputId = 'Selector', label = 'What happened to item...', choices = NULL,
                    selected=NULL, options = list(maxOptions = 5)
                ),
                verbatimTextOutput('ex_out'),  
            )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'Selector', choices = MyMap, server = TRUE, selected=NULL)
    ##updateSelectizeInput(session, 'Selector', choices = MyMap, server = FALSE, selected=NULL)    

    output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
      input[['Selector']]
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `MyMap` is a dataframe. What is `choices = MyMap` supposed to do? I've never seen a dataframe passed to the `choices` argument.

Comment: If the columns are 'label' and 'value', it'll map the selection to the corresponding value of the 'value'' column.  the problem here is that only the first 5 characters are used for search, and I haven't yet found how to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so basically selectizeInput seems to use the 5-character prefix for searching.  That's very limiting and doesn't seem to be user-modifiable.  However, autocomplete_input does more or less the same thing and works well. 
 I recommend switching to this widget instead:
https://rdrr.io/cran/dqshiny/man/autocomplete_input.html